# GET http://localhost:3000/user/authenticated 401 (Unauthorized) how to bypass this error for certain requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

GET http://localhost:3000/user/authenticated 401 (Unauthorized) how to bypass this error for certain requests that the user does not need to be authenticated. For example an eCommerce store has the ability to display all the products to any visitor to that website however a seller would need to login. So how I bypass this with code I have created below? Sorry if this is poorly explained I new to backend and user authentication.

Please note I have no issue in getting the data, the process works fine. Its just the error appears and I want to remove it.

Below is how I have set up user authentication the error stems from the iaAuthenticated section I will highlight where.

```
export default {
    login : user => {
        return fetch('/user/login', {
            method : "post",
            body : JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res=>{
            if(res.status !== 401)
                return res.json().then(data => data);
            else
                return {isAuthenticated : false, user: {username : ""}}
        })
    },
    
    register : user => {
        return fetch('/user/register', {
            method : "post",
            body : JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data);
    },

    logout : ()=> {
        return fetch('/user/logout')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data);
    },
    isAuthenticated : () => {
        (error appears from this line)return fetch ('/user/authenticated')
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.status !== 401)
                return res.json().then(data => data);
            else
                return {isAuthenticated : false, user: {username : ""}}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show backend code(routes)?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that can be done.

1. Move the file from the dir to a different dir above.
   If this makes the page work then the file was the problem
2. Try seeing any configuration changes you madfe to your apache2.conf or .conf or .htaccess.
   If you changes the settings and this works you can try again to see if your file will work.